# Android newbie installing Eclipse, having issues

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a web developer, new to app development and Java/Android. I am about to follow some tutorials to get started learning but I'm running into a wall. The Android dev site says the recommended way to build Android apps is in Java using the Eclipse plug in. So I downloaded Eclipse Classic and unzipped it on to get this error:

"A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse.

No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
/Users//Desktop/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH"

Any idea what the issue is and how I can fix it? Again, newbie to java, jre, android, so I apologize if this question has already been asked. In my research I've discovered that most of the posts or solutions I've found are tough for me to follow. There's always a few unclear items that are probably prohibiting me from getting the answer I need. So I'm hoping someone can walk me through installing or configuring whatever I need to regarding Java so I can continue installing Eclipse and begin learning.

I should probably note that I'm on Mac OSX 10.6.6 Snow Leopard. Please let me know if you need any other info. Thanks so much in advance for any and all help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mac is telling the truth, it can't find a JRE or JDK - make sure one is in your PATH and then try again.

[edit]

At the command prompt:

```
whereis java
```

and got /usr/bin/java.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/java
```

showed a symlink to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java.

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
```

indicates that all my java's are located here.

So, as long as /usr/bin/java exists, it should be linked to your current jdk.  If it's not, you're probably going to have to do a little googling to find out why.

Apple contends that all the java stuff is ready to go on your machine (as it was on mine).  See [here](http://developer.apple.com/java/faq/) for more information.

[/edit]

Comment: I'm assuming this means to make sure the jdk/jre path is added to the PATH environment variable correct? If so, how would I go about adding it, and would the path to add be? Apologies again, but I'm new to the Mac scene as well. Thanks again!

Comment: "whereis java" gives me the same result, but "ls -1 /usr/bin/java" simply gives me "/usr/bin/java" again. Then an idea struck me. In the original error message it was looking in a certain location within the application directory, which didnt exist. So I created the folder structure it was looking for, then copied the java alias from /usr/bin/ and eclipse no longer threw that error message. So far it seems to work, but I have yet to actually build and compile anything so we'll see if it holds up, but so far so good. Anyways thanks for your help and quick replies, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Download a java jdk from Oracle.

Comment: (Don't forget to install it...)

Comment: I'm using a Mac, and apparently Apple supplies their own version of Java on Macs out of the box. Everywhere I've tried to download the JDK from there are no options for Mac....

Comment: Oh, I thought that they had stopped doing that.